# How to set all months length in 30 days in java

Tags: java, date, calendar

i want all months last 30 days. Can i achieve this with java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar in java?. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want the 1,2, or 3 months that the last 30 days fall into?

Comment: Why do you want the calendar to lie?

Comment: "I'd like every hour to last for 70 minutes.  Can I achieve this with Java?" - no.  Sounds like specialized business rules that need to be in your code.

Comment: it may give segmentation fault =)

Comment: I want all working weeks to last 1 day, unfortunately I doubt this is something I can achieve using Java, or any programming language.

Comment: @SLaks: In what way would it be "lying"? Calendars are entirely human concepts - and there are various ones used in various different cultures. A calendar which had exactly 360 days in every year would be far from the strangest idea in the history of calendaring...

Comment: As said before, _why_ do you want all months to be 30 days in length.  This is certainly possible - but do you want the years to eventually 'true up', or do you want them to get farther and farther behind?  And if this is related to accounting rules in terms of counting days... there are probably better ways to accomplish this.

Comment: in my assignment we are expected to develop banking system. My teacher said all months should last 30 days. So this is why i asked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's certainly got nothing to do with `java.util.Date`, which doesn't really "know" about months (aside from deprecated APIs).

You'd have to create your own implementation of `Calendar`. Good luck with that - it won't be fun.

Alternatively, you could use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) which is a much nicer date/time API anyway. The [`CopticChronology`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/chrono/CopticChronology.html) *nearly* does what you want, except it adds a thirteenth month with 5 or 6 days. I suspect you could fairly easily use that as the basis for a "just 12 months of 30 days" chronology though.

Comment: Hello! I am from the year `2019`. Have a look at our Java 8+ `java.time` API! Here's a future link for the `Java 12` docs if you happen to come across this answer 2014 onwards: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html